# Couldn't connect to node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Exception: Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8501.

Comment: More infos required! Where you're connecting from? To what are you connecting (RPC?)? ...

Comment: I am trying to access my Geth node through RPC from my UI (using web3.js)
geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner'  --rpccorsdomain "*"

and in the front-end :
 web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8501"));